# Arithmetic overflow error on decimal field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a field cost with values `0.987878656435798654` , `0.765656787898767`
I am trying to figure out what would be the datatype for this.

When I give  `decimal 15,15` and trying to load data it is throwing me an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not allocating any length to the value *before* the decimal.

`DECIMAL (15, 15)` means that it has a precision of 15 digits after the decimal, but only enough room for 15 digits total - thus leaving no room for values greater than `1`.

This means that `DECIMAL (15, 15)` only supports values in the following range:
`-0.999999999999999` to `0.999999999999999` (15 digits after the decimal).

You have `18` digits in your first example, so I would recommend using something like `DECIMAL (21, 18)`

`DECIMAL (21, 18)` will support values in the range from: `-999.999999999999999999` to `999.999999999999999999` (18 digits after the decimal).

But, you should analyze your own data to see what the maximum value would be that you need to support.

Comment: Unless you specifically don't want more decimals, keep in mind that from 10 to 19 digits, the field uses 9 bytes, and from 20 to 28 it uses 13, so you could use `DECIMAL(28,25)` (for example), gaining more precision with the same amount of storage bytes (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). You may also want to consider using money types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx, although it only has up to 4 decimal digits (usually more than enough for money, maybe not your case).

Comment: My Len of the data in the  field are 14
12
15
13 and i still get that error. i am not sure what i am doing wrong.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT LEN(YourColumn)
FROM YourTable
```

Then , if they are below 1 every time, try this...

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(X,X-1),YourColumn)
```

Where X is what is returned in the LEN statement. and X-1 is one less than that.

Remember, it's `DECIMAL(TotalLength,Precision)` so you need to make sure have enough space for the total value.